# Vue.js methods or a separate js file?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, frameworks

What are the differences between declaring functions under methods in vue.js instance compared to declaring them in a separate js file?
Which are the benefits in using vue.js methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods in a Vue component are scoped to that component, so more than one component could have (as an example) a `handleClick` function without conflicting with the others.